# How to position a CSS background image to not collapse the entire website?

Tags: html, css

I have a question about how to position a background picture using CSS.

One simple use in style.css is `background-image: URL('dishes.jpg');`
The challenge is that it will appear on the webpage and cover the entire first part of the menu.

In this case in  looks like this:
  element for the menu (this is covered by it and I would like to position under this.)

and  elements - On this I need to set positioning in the background.

IN CSS file, I targeted this element like

```
.something p {
 background-image: url('dishes.jpg');
}
```

After this, the background image is loading the right and on the menu - cover the entire menu/div element.

**Question:** How could I manage this to appear under the menu and the text and the form element(email submit button) appear on this?

One picture tells thousands word so to speak here is the thing:
[image]

Here you can see that I need to place it like this:

[image]

So the black picture with dishes will be the background picture which should appear under my menu/div element instead of to jump on that and collapse it.

Comment: Would you try this: `background-image: url('dishes.jpg') center 200px no-repeat;`

Comment: It maded it disappear the entire one if I write what you say like this:
#main {
  background-image: url('Images/dishes.jpg') center 200px no-repeat;
}

I need to push down it under the menu.

Comment: Opps, should be this: `background: url('dishes.jpg') center 200px no-repeat;`

Comment: I found it! 
Thank you your fast answer. I played with the #main because some elements appear on the top and with CSS, I created several selectors and manage it on the center. 
Then I noticed this spectacular appealing thing on my site. So I deleted it. The problem is very simple I placed it in the Header.. 

Thank you your fast answers!